# Feature image option won't show in portfolio

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am making a wordpress theme 
But the problem is i can not enable feature image option in Portfolio
I have added the following code in the function.php
add_theme_support( "post-thumbnails", array('portfolio', 'post'));

This code is working for posts but not for portfolio

is it because of any of these plugins that i am using

Advanced Custom Fields
Custom Post Type UI
Akismet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnKl2.png)

Answer (score 3):

try this in fucntion.php file

```
function custom_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array('post', 'page', 'popup') );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_setup');
```